# String Formatting in C# to handle decimal places

Tags: c#, string-formatting, jsonserializer

In the Web API there is a Number data type field we retrieve from oracle DB and return in JSON format. Since it is of Number type it shows in the result 364578.0 so now using the string format we are trying to avoid the decimal point like

```
 serializer.Serialize(writer, string.Format("{0:n0}",reader[i]));
```

It did solve the issue, it does return the result omitting the decimal spaces but  shows result like 364,578 I am just checking if there is any possibility that we can return the result like 364578

Comment: Why do you care about that `.` anyways? Why not just serialize it as-is?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The client API user was requesting if we can remove the decimal places. Is there any drawback of formatting it.

Comment: In such cases I always wonder if I would workaround or fix the problem. In this case you might need to workaround it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a little discussion in comments. You don't seem to be able to fix the problem since the API is out of your hands. That means that you have to workaround it.

From your question I understand the other end expects an integer instead of a decimal. Okay, well let's give it an `int` then:

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, Convert.ToInt32(reader[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, string.Format("{0:f0}",reader[i]));
```

The `F` format does not use thousand separators. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom formatting

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, (decimal)reader[i].ToString("0.#");
```